# Excel split given number into sum of other numbers

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I'm trying to write formulae that will split a given number into the sum of 4 other numbers.

The other numbers are 100,150,170 and 200 so the formula would be 
**x = a*100+b*150+c*170+d*200** where x is the given number and a,b,c,d are integers.

My spreadsheet is set up as where col B are x values, and C,D,E,F are a,b,c,d respectively (see below).

```
   B  |  C  |  D  |  E  |  F  |
  100    1     0     0     0
  150    0     1     0     0   
  200    0     0     0     1  
  250    1     1     0     0  
  370    0     0     1     1   
  400    0     0     0     2
```

I need formulae for columns C,D,E,F (which are a,b,c,d in the formula)

Your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Apologies for the table. I'm new to stack overflow so didn't quite know how to get it to work...

Comment: You are actually there... just type this in cell G1 `=(C1*100)+(D1*150)+(E1*170)+(F1*200)`. Then fill them down. Admittedly, I'm a bit confused by your post, but this seems to be what you are asking...

Comment: @ScottHoltzman, he wants to know how to calculate C,D,E & F, given only B

Comment: Thanks at @SeanCheshire! Isn't that kind of impossible. Take the number 500. How you would know if it's 2 values of 100 and 2 values of 150, 5 values of 100, or 2 of 200 and 1 of 100...

Comment: I don't think there's a formula that would work. It would be something for the solver - and you also have to consider that the last one is shown as `0 0 0 2`, but could also be `4 0 0 0`

Comment: @ScottHoltzman is right. Too many unknowns too few equations. Unless. Unless! the whole table is a system of equations, then there is enough information.

Comment: @SeanCheshire - exactly what I was saying with how to split the numbers.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman using just 2 tiny assumptions it is solvable using quite simple formulas ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE**:

Based on the research below, for input numbers greater than 730 and/or for all actually divisible input numbers use the following formulas:

```
100s: =CHOOSE(MOD(ROUNDUP([@number]/10;0); 20)+1;
       0;1;1;0;1;1;0;1;0;0;1;0;0;1;0;0;1;0;1;1)
150s: =CHOOSE(MOD(ROUNDUP([@number]/10;0); 10)+1;
       0;0;1;1;0;1;1;0;0;1)
170s: =CHOOSE(MOD(ROUNDUP([@number]/10;0); 5)+1;
       0;3;1;4;2)
200s: =CEILING(([@number]-930)/200;1) + 
       CHOOSE(MOD(ROUNDUP([@number]/10;0); 20)+1;
       4;1;2;0;2;3;1;3;1;2;4;2;3;0;2;3;0;3;0;1)
```

- `MOD(x; 20)` will return numbers 0 - 19, `CHOOSE(x;a;b;...)` will return n-th argument based on the first argument (1=>second argument, ...)
- see [more info about CHOOSE](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/choose-HP005209013.aspx)
- use `,` instead of `;` based on your Windows language&region settings

---

let's start with the assumption that you want to preferably use **200s over 170s over 150s over 100s** - i.e. `300=200+100` instead of `300=2*150` and follow the logical conclusions:

1. the result set can only contain **at most 1 `100`**, **at most 1 `150`**, **at most 4 `170s`** and unlimited number of `200s` (*i started with 9 `170s` because 1700=8x200+100, but in reality there were at most 4*)
2. there are only 20 possible subsets of (100s, 150s, 170s) - 2*2*5 options
3. 930 is the largest input number without any `200s` in the result set
4. based on observation of the data points, the subset repeats periodically for

   `number = 740*k + 10*l, k>1, l>0` - i'm not an expert on reverse-guessing on periodic functions from data, but here is my work in progress *(charted data points are from the table at the bottom of this answer)*

[image: periodic functions for denominations]

- the functions are probably more complicated, if i manage to get them right, i'll update the answer
- anyway for numbers smaller than 740, more tweaking of the formulas or a lookup table are needed *(e.g. there is no way to get 730, so the result should be the same as for 740)*

---

Here is my solution based on lookup formulas:
[image: match+index formulas]

Following is the **python script** i used to generate the data points, **formulas** from the picture and the **60-row table** itself in csv format *(sorted as needed by the `match` function)*:

```
headers = ("100s", "150s", "170s", "200s")
table = {}
for c200 in range(30, -1, -1):
    for c170 in range(9, -1, -1):
        for c150 in range(1, -1, -1):
            for c100 in range(1, -1, -1):
                nr = 200*c200 + 170*c170 + 150*c150 + 100*c100
                if nr not in table and nr <= 6000:
                    table[nr] = (c100, c150, c170, c200)
print("number\t" + "\t".join(headers))
for r in sorted(table):
    c100, c150, c170, c200 = table[r]
    print("{:6}\t{:2}\t{:2}\t{:2}\t{:2}".format(r, c100, c150, c170, c200))
__________

=IF(E$1<740; 0; INT((E$1-740)/200))
=E$1 - E$2*200
=MATCH(E$3; table[number]; -1)
=INDEX(table[number]; E$4)
=INDEX(table[100s]; E$4)
=INDEX(table[150s]; E$4)
=INDEX(table[170s]; E$4)
=INDEX(table[200s]; E$4) + E$2
__________

number,100s,150s,170s,200s
940,0,0,2,3
930,1,1,4,0
920,0,1,1,3
910,0,0,3,2
900,1,0,0,4
890,0,1,2,2
880,0,0,4,1
870,1,0,1,3
860,0,1,3,1
850,1,1,0,3
840,1,0,2,2
830,0,1,4,0
820,1,1,1,2
810,1,0,3,1
800,0,0,0,4
790,1,1,2,1
780,1,0,4,0
770,0,0,1,3
760,1,1,3,0
750,0,1,0,3
740,0,0,2,2
720,0,1,1,2
710,0,0,3,1
700,1,0,0,3
690,0,1,2,1
680,0,0,4,0
670,1,0,1,2
660,0,1,3,0
650,1,1,0,2
640,1,0,2,1
620,1,1,1,1
610,1,0,3,0
600,0,0,0,3
590,1,1,2,0
570,0,0,1,2
550,0,1,0,2
540,0,0,2,1
520,0,1,1,1
510,0,0,3,0
500,1,0,0,2
490,0,1,2,0
470,1,0,1,1
450,1,1,0,1
440,1,0,2,0
420,1,1,1,0
400,0,0,0,2
370,0,0,1,1
350,0,1,0,1
340,0,0,2,0
320,0,1,1,0
300,1,0,0,1
270,1,0,1,0
250,1,1,0,0
200,0,0,0,1
170,0,0,1,0
150,0,1,0,0
100,1,0,0,0
0,0,0,0,0
```

Comment: Thanks for this. It looks really interesting. I think most of my values will be below 740 but I'll do a lookup table for these value and use your method for any over 740. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you want as many of the highest values as possible (so 500 would be 2*200 + 100) try this approach assuming the number to split in B2 down:

Insert a header row with the 4 numbers, e.g. 100, 150, 170 and 200 in the range C1:F1

Now in F2 use this formula:

`=INT(B2/F$1)`

and in C2 copied across to E2

`=INT(($B2-SUMPRODUCT(D$1:$G$1,D2:$G2))/C$1)`

Now you can copy the formulas in C2:F2 down all columns

That should give the results from your table

Comment: formulas won't work - this fails on 250, as your method will give 1 in column F (for 200) and then have nowhere to put the remaining 50.

Comment: Thanks Sean. Good point, on my cursory analysis I had thought that my results matched those required - back to the drawing board......The above is an adaptation of a method successfully used for splitting a currency amount into the correct number of notes/coins, assuming you want the largest number of high denomination notes.

Comment: Thanks for your help so far. I do want the largest number of high denominations. Is there a way to do it VBA?

Comment: @barryhoudini I've tried your formulae. I need it to round up to the nearest component i.e. if x = 120 it puts a 1 in the 150 column and not the 100 column.

Comment: It might be difficult to satisfy all requirements with a formula based solution - as per the comments on your question - are 100, 150, 170 and 200 the real values you are using or is that a simplified example? Perhaps you could give some more examples of how you want the amounts to be split, especially when "x" can't be divided exactly between those amounts

Comment: Yes 100, 150, 170, 200 are the real values I'm using. Some examples are: x=120 gives 1 in 150 column, x=240 give 1 in 100 and 150 columns, x=360 gives 1 in 200 and 1 in 170 columns. Essentially, I need it to round up the nearest combination of 100,150,170,200 with the smallest values a,b,c,d.